# How to get dumpstate logs in samsung galaxy grand?

Tags: logging

While working on my app, I have faced app crash. But I can't get any dumpstate log from `data/log` folder. So what is the solution to get dumpstate. Or I have to create any folder on my app name in data folder?

Advance thanks for your help..

Comment: Maybe you want to check that on SO: [writing dumpstate to file android](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9011056/2533433)? (also see: [dumpsys and dumpstate](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#dumpsys)) I think this is rather development related. We cover the end-user's view-point here, development questions are better asked at SO.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an adb shell to get dumpstate logs ***in this case***.

Every Samsung device has a built-in tools like **`SysDump`**, just follow these steps:

1) Open the Phone app in your device and type: **`*#9900#`**

2) Depending on how much detailed logs you would like to get change **`Debug Level`** and **`Silent log`** options (by default Debug Level is **`Disabled/LOW`** and Silent Log is turned Off)

3) Click on **`Run dumpstate/logcat/modem log`** (should be first option) wait until process finishes

4) Click **`Copy to sdcard(include CP Ramdump)`**. This is important step because by default collected logs will be stored in **`/data/log`** directory, which is under root permissions so you can't access to it without root permissions

5) Your logs will be stored in **`/log`** directory on your DEVICE STORAGE.(this means that you don't need root access to find it just use file manager).

Comment: If the device doesn't have a dialer, enter `(+30012012732+` into the calculator and then proceed entering `*#9900#`

Comment: Still working on Samsung Galaxy Tab S8 Ultra. The file itself is a ZIP named like: `dumpState_<deviceid>_<datetime>.zip`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create the dumpstate file from a PC (using `adb`), run this command from a shell:

```
adb shell dumpstate > dumpstate.log
```

This will create the file `dumpstate.log` in the current directory on your PC. You can use this as part of a bug report.

Comment: Could not get this to work on Samsung Galaxy Tab S8 Ultra: `/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/dumpstate: Permission denied`. Not sure if one can get around that permission issue without root.